# Adjusting Keyboard in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitextfield

I'm trying to set up a UITextField in a UIScrollView and make the keyboard adjust the scroll view as needed for editing. The code I'm using isn't working, is there any additional setup I need to do with the delegates or something?

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [myScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,textField.center.y-140) animated:YES];
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [myScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0) animated:YES];

    return YES;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [myScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 750)];
    UITextField *title = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 410, 300, 30)];
    title.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:25];
    title.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    title.placeholder = @"Sample Text";
    [myScrollView addSubview:title];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In viewDidLoad, you should add this for the delegates:

```
title.delegate = self;
```

If you see warning, in header file .h add

```
<UITextFieldDelegate>
```